# Jquery Put serialize data into array

Tags: jquery, arrays, serialization, each

I want to get all the data from my form and put it into an accessible array. Here's what I have so far:

```
var data = $("#everything").serializeArray();
var test = [];
$(data).each(function(index, element) {
    test[element] = element.val();
});
```

I tried this:

```
alert(data["fname"]);
```

But that returned "undefined" even though there was something in the textbox, which is why i have to do that .each method. But now when I do

```
alert(test["fname"]);
```

It doesn't even pop up the message. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I just want to put all the form data into an array that I can access by id or name of the inputs.

Comment: what does console.log( data ); show...

Comment: [It's working for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/EVdAw/) Could you post your code? Also, be sure that your inputs have name attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things about your code... First `test` is an array but you're using it as an object like `test[element]`, this will cause trouble. Then `serializeArray` creates an array of objects, each object contains `name` and `value` so there's no `element.val()`, plus I'm pretty sure `element` is the DOM element so you'd have to either wrap it in jQuery like `$(element).val()` or use the native property like `element.value` but again, this won't get you the value you're looking for. Try this:

```
var data = $('#myform').serializeArray();
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
    obj[data[i].name] = data[i].value;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/KRbPg/